# Can't run Mongodb-community server from brew services

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, homebrew

I'm not being able to start mongodb community server. Don't know what the problem is, tried updating brew and reinstalling many times. Homebrew and mongodb-community, both are updated to their latest versions. After i run `brew services start mongodb-community` command, it throws this error in the terminal.

```
Error: undefined method `plist_startup' for #<Formula mongodb-community (stable) /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community.rb>
Did you mean?  plist_name
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/formula_wrapper.rb:71:in `service_startup?'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:280:in `service_load'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:122:in `block in start'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:97:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:97:in `start'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/commands/start.rb:12:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/cmd/services.rb:130:in `services'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:86:in `<main>'
```

After i reinstall the Homebrew and mongodb-community, it works only once after i restart my laptop and throws the same error again in the next start.

Comment: Do you try to run the service more than once?

Comment: Yes, every time it throws this same error. It was working perfectly until yesterday and then there was this new update for mongodb compass and i updated it last night. Now from today morning, it's broken.

Comment: Review your configuration file. It might be reverted to default by the update.